# kubernetes service account secrets is not listed

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

I created a secret of type `service-account` using the below code. The secret got created but when I run the `kubectl get secrets` the service-account secret is not listed. Where am I going wrong

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: secret-sa-sample
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/service-account.name: "sa-name"
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
data:
  # You can include additional key value pairs as you do with Opaque Secrets
  extra: YmFyCg==
```

````
kubectl create -f  sa-secret.yaml
secret/secret-sa-sample created```
````

Comment: did you create a serviceaccount?

Comment: yes. The above yaml file is what I posted to the API server. I am not finding the service account

Comment: No, did you create a serviceaccount BEFORE you applied the secret?

Comment: `kubectl create sa sa-name`

Comment: I was able to see the secret in my local env after creating service account as suggested by @Matt

Answer (score 0):

it might have been created in default namespace.
Specify namespace explicitly using `-n $NS` argument to kubectl

Comment: No. It is not created in any of the namespace. I verified

Comment: Did you try this command? `kubectl get secrets -A | grep secret-sa-sample`

Comment: I am seeing all the secrets except `secret-sa-sample`